# avoid fatal guzzle exception error on api requests

Tags: 9

how can i avoid fatal error due to ?

```
 |GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host|
```

My code here do not catch it

```
try {
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
      $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);     
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('amu_hal')->error('this url aint good'.$url);
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the `$url` variable equal to something?

Comment: Is there more code than this? What is `$url`?

Comment: my question is not how to make the request correct but how to avoid a fatal error if the url is not correct.

Comment: That is what I am asking, how is the `$url` formed? It is user input? Can you validate it with the `Url` class (create a `Url` object, then pass `$url->toString()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example on how to catch this error:

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

    try {
         // example of status code 500
         $url='http://httpstat.us/500';
         $client = new Client();
         $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
         $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);     
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
    // catches all ClientExceptions
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    // catches all RequestExceptions
}
```